# Asynchronous task in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I need to run my crawler from my web administration. I have 2 ideas to do it:

- Run the crawler as an external process. It's simple, but I didn't want it.
- The crawler will be part of my website and I'll run it in the background. I think it's a better solution. I am looking for something like https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/. Is in there any way to do it?

The applications are written in C# and use .NET Core on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

asynchronous task != background task and the tools for one do not necessarily work for the other. ASP.NET is great at asyncronous work, but is notoriously finicky at background work.

Your first option of doing a separate process really is the simplest solution and will likely be the most reliable.

If you really want the background work to run from inside the ASP.NET site you will need to find a background work library that works on ASP.NET Core, I normally use [Hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io/) but I have never tried to use it with ASP.NET Core. It apppears that it can work with ASP.NET Core but [it is a little rough to set up](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/365) (EDIT: [Or maybe it does not work with core](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/hangfire-in-asp-net-core-rc2/2039), you will need to do your own research to find a library that works).

Answer (score 0):

You should really reconsider to run it as a separate process.